# Why do I get errors when importing tfjs-node?

Tags: vuejs2, tensorflow.js

```
import * as tfn from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

throws me followed warnings:

```
WARNING  Compiled with 4 warnings                                                                                                                                                                 15:06:46  
warning  in ./node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js    
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression    
warning  in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js   
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node-gyp' in 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Team\my-app\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'   
warning  in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js    
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'npm' in 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Team\my-app\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util'   
warning  in ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/index.html

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html>
```

Why is that? (vue: 2.7.8)

Webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: './server.js',
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.'),
    filename: 'server.bundle.js'
  }
};
```

Package versions:

```
├── @tensorflow/tfjs-converter@3.19.0
├── @tensorflow/tfjs-core@3.19.0
├── @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.19.0
├── @tensorflow/tfjs@3.19.0
├── aws-sdk@2.1195.0
```

(Please let me know if you need information for further details)

Also tried a workaround with Windows Subsystem for Linux which gives me followed error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.19.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.19.0 install script.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error, it's likely that you are using Python 3. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-node), "Windows & OSX build support for node-gyp requires Python 2.7". In the event that you are using the correct version of Python, see the [Windows troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md) for further troubleshooting information.

Conversely, you can use [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), and then interact with TensorFlow.js through Linux. My colleague on the team who uses Windows prefers this method, so I'd recommend it.

Comment: Hey Jen Person, thanks for your answer. I have installed Python 2.7, but then it occurs a new error from node pre gyp:   ``npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is 2.7.18 - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED`` my node-pre-gyp version ist: ``node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0``